# Displaying elements of an arraylist

Tags: java, eclipse

I am trying to display the elements of my `ArrayList<LibraryItem>` in an action listener method by calling a `printlibrary` method from another class. I keep getting:

`The method printLibrary(ArrayList<LibraryItem>) in the type Library is not applicable for the arguments.`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong could you please help me.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Library {

    private ArrayList<LibraryItem> items;

    public Library() {
        items = new ArrayList<LibraryItem>();
    }

    public void addItem(LibraryItem newItem) {
        items.add(newItem);
    }

    public LibraryItem searchForItem (String name) {
        for(LibraryItem searchForItem: items) {
            if(searchForItem.getName().equals(name))
                return searchForItem;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void printLibrary(ArrayList<LibraryItem> items) {
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(items.get(i));
        }
    }
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    String t = title.getText();     
    int y = Integer.parseInt(year.getText());
    int q = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());

    library.addItem(new LibraryItem(t,y,q)); 

    library.printLibrary(); -------->>>> ERROR HERE!!!
}                                                                                                     this is the edited version and the error                                               public void printLibrary(ArrayList<LibraryItem> items) {
        for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(items.get(i));
        }
    }
}      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
    String t = title.getText();     
    int y = Integer.parseInt(year.getText());
    int q = Integer.parseInt(quantity.getText());

    library.addItem(new LibraryItem(t,y,q)); 

    library.printLibrary(); 
}                                                                                              this is my code for libraryitem class `                                                                public class LibraryItem
```

{

```
    private String name;
    private int year, quantity;

   LibraryItem(String nameIn, int yearIn, int quantityIn)
   {
       name = nameIn;
       year = yearIn;
       quantity = quantityIn;



   }



public boolean rent()
{


    if(quantity > 0) 

    {
         quantity--;

    }
      return true;
}






    public String toString()
   {
return name + " " +"has"+ " " +quantity+ "books on loan";


   }

    public String getName()
   {
return name;

   }


   public int getQuantity()
   {

   return quantity;
   }

   public int getYear()
   {

   return year;
   }


   }
```

`

this is my code for library     `                                                                            import java.util.ArrayList;

```
 public class Library {

private ArrayList<LibraryItem> items;




public Library()
{
    items = new ArrayList<LibraryItem>();
}



public void addItem(LibraryItem newItem)
{
    items.add(newItem);

}

public LibraryItem searchForItem (String name)

{
    for(LibraryItem searchForItem: items)
    {
        if(searchForItem.getName().equals(name) )

    return searchForItem;


}
    return null;
}

public void printLibrary()
{


    for(int i = 0; i< items.size(); i++)
    {

        System.out.println(items.get(i));
    }


}
```

}

```
                                   `
```

Comment: How is your `printLibrary` method declared? Does it accept any arguments? Also, why is it `static`?

Comment: Your printLibrary method has a parameter of ArrayList type. But in your action listener your calling it with no arguments. Can you explain why?

Answer (score 2):

Look at your call:

```
library.printLibrary();
```

Now look at the declaration:

```
public static void printLibrary(ArrayList<LibraryItem>items)
```

This is a *static* method, with a parameter which is a list. You're trying to call it as an *instance* method (which Java allows even when calling a static method, unfortunately, but which should be avoided anyway) but not supplying any arguments.

Given that `Library` already has a list of items, I suggest you just change the declaration to make it a parameterless instance method:

```
public void printLibrary()
```

... leaving the body of the method the same, which will then pick up the *instance* variable `items`.

Comment: Thanks for your help that has seemed to get rid of my error! but the elements of my array list are still not being displayed when click to add an element to my array list via my interface. I get these messages.                                                                Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at LibraryFrame.actionPerformed(LibraryFrame.java:62)
 at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)

Comment: @user3198936: Now that you've included the message... which is line 62? Where are you declaring `library` and how are you initializing it?

Comment: public class LibraryItem 
{
 private String name;
 private int year, quantity;

    LibraryItem(String nameIn, int yearIn, int quantityIn)
    {
     name = nameIn;
     year = yearIn;
     quantity = quantityIn;
      }
 public boolean rent()
 {
  if(quantity > 0) 
   
  {
    quantity--;
    }
          return true;
    }
 public String toString()
   {
 return name + " " +"has"+ " " +quantity+ "books on loan";
     }
    public String getName()
   {
 return name;
}
   public int getQuantity()
   {
    
    return quantity;}
   
   public int getYear()
   {
   
   return year;
   }
    }

Comment: @user3198936: Please don't dump large amounts of code in comments. Edit the question instead. Although to be honest this should all be in a new question now - I've answered the question you asked. The next problem is a different one.

Comment: I have now edited the question and posted my code for library

Comment: @user3198936: You haven't put the code for LibraryItem into the question, you haven't included the exception you've received, you haven't told us which is line 62 in LibraryFrame, and most importantly you haven't posted a *new question* as I suggested. We've answered the question you originally asked - please use one question for each problem, otherwise it ends up being very confusing.

Comment: @user3198936: In fact, it looks like you haven't edited the question *at all* in the last 20 minutes...

Comment: i have edited the question sorry for the inconvenience this is my first time using the site

Comment: @user3198936: There's still no stack trace, still no indication of line 62, still no indication of where `library` is declared or how it's initialized, and it's still the same question. I'm done with this question, I'm afraid - there are only so many different ways I can say "Ask a new question, your original one has been solved." Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints and http://tinyurl.com/so-list

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `printLibrary(ArrayList<LibraryItem> items)`, yet you call it without passing in any arguments.

The declaration:

```
public static void printLibrary(ArrayList<LibraryItem>items)
{
    for(int i = 0; i< items.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(items.get(i));
    }
}
```

And the call to it:

```
library.printLibrary();
```

The call to the printLibrary() method requires an ArrayList, so instead you would want to call it like:

```
library.printLibrary(items);
```

However, you should change how the method is declared if all you are doing is printing out a information from a private data member of the class. A better declaration would be:

```
public void printLibrary()
{
    for(int i = 0; i< items.size(); i++)
    {
        System.out.println(items.get(i));
    }
}
```

Now, your library's printLibrary() method will print each item in your `items` data member. If you change your declaration to this, you can leave the call as `library.printLibrary()`.